# READ FPDMA QUEUED error

Tags: linux-mint, xfce

Broke my hard disk (Windows OS) some time back. Thought I'd my hands at Linux and a friend of mine recommended Linux Mint Xfce.
I put it in a USB pendrive (using unetbootin). It worked well a few times but now the loading screen keeps just well, loading.
During boot, this "READ FPDMA QUEUED" error shows up a lot. Well, it was showing up when Linux was working as well. But when I use the same USB for booting in other systems this error doesn't show up there and works smoothly and reliably. Any help would be appreciated in this regard.
I'm completely new to Linux and wouldn't mind up reading/understanding a bit if I have to. I just want my system to work with a reliable OS (Linux) and right now, I'm unable to understand if the problem is in unetbootin, or this specific Linux or with my system motherboard/BIOS itself.

Comment: Can you copy the errors from the log file itself? `sudo dmesg > /tmp/dmesg.txt` should put the whole kernel ring-buffer log there, you can then open it with a text editor and copy some lines around the error even if you are not sure they are related.

Comment: Can I do it without the Linux booting?

Comment: Oh, it is not booting now, then you could take a picture of the screen with the errors. You can also try another USB port. Consider rewriting the question to make it clear, what works and what doesn't. For example, "booting in other systems", do you mean FreeBSD, Windows, ... in the same computer, or booting other computers.